# How submodules communicate

Tags: connection, simulation, omnet++

I am new to OMNET and there is something unclear to me. I know that we have compound modules, inside this module we can have nested other modules/submodules and so on until simpleModule. I know that if I have two modules I need to use gates to pass msg between them,  "in" gate to "out" gate of other module using channel. What I don t understand how communication flow inside communication module, I know that I must use gates in a same manner but do I require communication channel? I find that there is @direct option for gates is this type of gates used for inner communication between modules/submodules?

Answer (score 0):

The connections between submodules inside a compound module usually use [`IdealChannel`](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:channels-overview) and they do not require `@directIn` annotation. According to [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:recognized-gate-properties):

> `@directIn` should be used when the gate is an input gate that is intended for being used as a target for the `sendDirect()` method;